# Header dependency in automake

Tags: dependencies, automake, header-files

I'd like to create a `Makefile.am` file which generates one header file mentioned in a `xxx.c` file.

Let's say that `xxx.c` contains:

```
#include <version.h>
...
```

and that I have a rule to create it at the end of `Makefile.am`:

```
version.h:
       echo '#define VERSION "'`hg id`'"' > version.h.tmp
       cmp version.h.tmp version.h || mv version.h.tmp version.h
```

What do I have to change to make the `xxx.c` compilation depend on `version.h`? I tried `nodist_progname_SOURCES=version.h`, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
BUILT_SOURCES = version.h
```

All files mentioned as `BUILT_SOURCES` will be built before any of the normal compilation rules run.

However, this will create a slight problem: As `version.h` will need to be rebuilt on every `make` invocation, the recompilation of every `foo.c` file which `#include`s `version.h` will be triggered again on every `make` run. We would prefer if the recompilation only happens when there is actually something that has changed.

To get around this problem, use a `BUILT_SOURCES` dependency on a stamp file which is  "created" every time (it never is actually created, so the build rule runs every time). The build rule for that stamp file creates a new `version.h` file as `version.h.tmp`, and only copies `version.h.tmp` to `version.h` if `version.h.tmp` is actually different from `version.h` (just like your `version.h` rule does). So if nothing has changed in `version.h`, its timestamp (mtime) remains the same, and no build of objects depending on `version.h` is triggered:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = version.stamp

version.stamp:
        echo '#define VERSION "'`hg id`'"' > version.h.tmp
        cmp version.h.tmp version.h || mv version.h.tmp version.h
```

This solution will do what you are asking for.

Unfortunately though, there will be a slight problem when you are building from a dist tarball: Then `hg id` will give you bogus information, and there probably is no `version.h` in your tarball, so the build will fail or contain bogus version information.

I have solved this issue for a the [xf86-video-radeonhd](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-radeonhd/) project which is using `git`. The `git-version.h` file generated in this solution contains some more version information than just a single version number. You can see this *update-only-if-different* solution of mine at the end of [git_version.sh](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-radeonhd/tree/git_version.sh) and the `BUILT_SOURCES` hookup (including handling of hopefully all *out-of-source-tree* and *from-dist-tarball* build cases) in [RadeonHD.am](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-radeonhd/tree/RadeonHD.am) if you are interested.

Comment: This works great, with one qualification.  From the automake manual: "It might be important to emphasize that BUILT_SOURCES is honored only by ‘make all’, ‘make check’ and ‘make install’. This means you cannot build a specific target (e.g., ‘make foo’) in a clean tree if it depends on a built source."  Still, it's the best solution I know of.

Comment: I guess if someone knows to specifically run `make foo`, you can reasonably assume some knowledge of what they are building, and thus whether they need to make sure manually that the BUILT_SOURCES are rebuilt.

Comment: You have to put these into a single line via the ``&&`` operator, otherwise make will be happy to parallelize your version.h construction.

Comment: @JanKundrát No. `make` only runs complete *recipes* for targets in _parallel_. The shell *commands* within a single target recipe are run _sequentially_.

Comment: Interesting -- when I tried to prepare a patch for Ragel http://repo.or.cz/w/ragel-jkt.git/commitdiff/a980ec473ee66ecb6dd3cc972819c33da8d1a8d7, the parallel build was broken when I did not use a single command. However, I cannot rule out some stupid mistake like using the ``>>`` redirection even on the first line. You must be right -- it wouldn't make any sense if the individual commands were run in parallel by default.